# Identity for sets

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**Identity for a set X:**

*The set X has an identity under the operation  if there is
an element **j** in set X such that **j * a =  a * j = a** for all elements **a** in set X.*

According to my college book the counting numbers don' t have an identity.

But for the operation * there is number 1 (= j ) such that a * 1 = 1 * a = a for all element a in set X.

**Why do natural numbers have no identity?**

Comment: Did you forget $0$ ?

Comment: The set Natural number or counting numbers begin with 1 - natural number of multiplicative identity . Zero is a natural number for additive identity and is an Integer or rational number. I don' t understand the question? Do both have to apply?

Comment: Sorry, in some countries we start counting at $0$. If you start with $1$, then the answer from Klaus is perfect: you need to say which operation you're looking at. They are probably talking about the sum, which doesn't have an identity (since you don't have $0$).

Comment: There is no operation giving, only the question:   "Which properties are true for the counting numbers, whole numbers, integers, rational numbers,
irrational numbers, and real numbers under the operation of addition?" The properties are: closed, identity and inverse. Thanks...

Comment: It sounds like your book is using a convention that distinguishes between "counting" numbers and "whole" numbers. Most likely the "whole" numbers include $0$ while the counting numbers do not. The terms "counting number," "whole number," and "natural number" are sometimes used interchangeably and sometimes not. See https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NaturalNumber.html for a discussion of the convention (or lack thereof) regarding $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operation is crucial here. $(\mathbb{N},\cdot)$ does have an identity, namely $1$ as you observed. For $(\mathbb{N},+)$ the identity would be $0$ and so it depends on your definition of $\mathbb{N}$ whether you include $0$ or not. I assume that your book uses the definition $\mathbb{N} = \{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ and so no number $j \in \mathbb{N}$ satifies $j + a = a$ for all $a \in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 1):

In comments the OP clarifies the question:

> "Which properties are true for the counting numbers, whole numbers,
> integers, rational numbers, irrational numbers, and real numbers under
> the operation of addition?" The properties are: closed, identity and
> inverse.

The verbatim quote, "Which properties ... addition?", can be tracked (via Google) to a Schaum's Outline, *College Algebra*, which defines the *counting* numbers as the set $\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ and the *whole* numbers as $\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$. The counting numbers thus, by definition, lack the additive identity $0$.